# R How to quickly get decision boundary for logistic regression

Tags: r, glm

We know how to plot decision boundaries for logistic regression and other classifier methods, however, I am not interested in a plot; but rather I want the exact value at which the binomial prediction is .50.

For example:

```
train=data.frame(1:20)
train$response=rep(1:0,10)
model=glm(response ~ poly(X1.20, 2), data=train, family=binomial)


train$X1.20[1]=10.5
predict(model, train[1,], type="response")
```

Leaves me with a decision boundary of 10.5 which I can find through trial and error with the predict() function, meaning a value of 10.5 for the independent variable gives a response of exactly .50. Is there an automated way to find what value will give a response of .50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the fact that a predicted value of zero from the logit model implies a response probability of 0.5. So you can just try to find a value of `x` that makes the predicted value as close to zero as possible. Here `deviationFromZero()` finds how far the predicted value from the model is from zero given any value of `x`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, response = rep(1:0, 10))
model <- glm(response ~ poly(x, 2), data = df, family = binomial)
deviationFromZero <- function(y) abs(predict(model, data.frame(x = y)))
boundary <- optimize(f = deviationFromZero, interval = range(df$x))

boundary
$minimum
[1] 10.5

$objective
           1 
1.926772e-16
```

Comment: For others that are interested in this, a speed improvement may exist from using nlm() instead of optimize(), however you must make sure to wrap the function in sum() so that it looks like sum(abs(predict(....

Comment: @JamesH You're right, I think `nlm` would certainly be faster. A gradient-based method would be faster in this case since everything is nice and continuous. `optimize` does something like a grid search so it's a bit slower (but in my experience, a bit more robust in other scenarios).